# Add leading zeros to a variable in command line prompt

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

So i'm trying to read folder names (bs000, bs001,..., bs104) in a for loop, my problem is that I can't seem to know how to add the leading zeros. Here is the piece of code.

```
   FOR /L %X IN (0,1,104) DO (
   robocopy E:\Bosphorus_3D_Face_DB\BosphorusDB\bs%X E:\Bosphorus_3D_Face_DB\bs%X *_CAU_A22A25_0.bnt)
```

I'm doing this in cmd.exe

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430642/win-bat-file-how-to-add-leading-zeros-to-a-variable-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   FOR /L %%X IN (0,1,104) DO (
       set "var=00%%X"
       set "var=!var:~-3!"
       robocopy "E:\Bosphorus_3D_Face_DB\BosphorusDB\bs!var!" "E:\Bosphorus_3D_Face_DB\bs!var!" "*_CAU_A22A25_0.bnt"
  )
   endlocal
```

Comment: that didn't work too, I get an out put like this : 'Source : E:\Original_Data\BosphorusDB\BosphorusDB\bs!var!\
  Dest : E:\Bosphorus_3D_Face_DB\bs!var!\'

Comment: If you see exclamation marks you have an copy & paste error. Have you forgotten `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` ?

Comment: This time I typed it myself, here is the screen shot for clarification (http://postimg.org/image/c5rz0pb6p/) and (http://postimg.org/image/vc563vroh/)

Comment: The first line with the "for" loop is missing.

Comment: Why toggle delayed expansion in this case? The number value never contains `!`, so you can simply enable delayed expansion before the loop and be done with it.

Comment: it is there, @dbenham what do you mean by "number value never contains !" ?

Comment: @dbenham -- yes you are right, but this is not the reason for the issue now.

Comment: @SalamKh - When a FOR variable like `%%X` contains `!`, the value will be corrupted if it is expanded while delayed expansion is enabled. This can happen, for example, when using FOR F to read a file. But your FOR /L `%%X` value is always numeric, so there is no worry about delayed expansion corruption in this case.

Comment: @Endoro - I agree the answer works fine. I'm just saying it can be simplified a bit.

Comment: I have tried the above using '%' instead of '!' I got something like this [click here](http://postimg.org/image/cmbpduzdf/)
What could be wrong?

Comment: Inside a for loop you can't read the changed value of '%' variables, you MUST always use the '!' notation.

Comment: salamkh - are you creating a batch file - not typing into the command prompt?

Comment: Ugly typo: 
I made an edit, please try it **now**. There are seven (7) lines (rows), please don't miss one. –

Comment: @foxidrive I'm writing in the command line. **Endoro** the loop does not wait for endlocal (it is after the loop)

Comment: @Endoro Now that I put the code in a .bat file, it works like a charm. Thanks a lot. But I'm still not sure why it didn't work on the command line prompt?

Comment: I suspected as much salamkh - It's a batch file.  Many things don't work at a command prompt, or have to be changed.  Most complex sets of statements need to be in a batch file.