# How do I add leading zeros to an image sequence in Windows Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430642/win-bat-file-how-to-add-leading-zeros-to-a-variable-in-a-for-loop) that explains how to add leading zeros to a sequence of numbers:

```
@echo off
set count=5
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (1, 1, %count%) do (
     set "formattedValue=000000%%i"
     echo !formattedValue:~-6!
)
```

This outputs

> ```
> 000001
> 000002
> 000003
> 000004
> 000005
> ```

I have image sequences that look like this:

> ```
> %1.j2c_0.j2c
> %1.j2c_10.j2c
> %1.j2c_100000.j2c
> ```

I would like to always have 6 numbers:

> ```
> %1.j2c_000000.j2c
> %1.j2c_000010.j2c
> %1.j2c_100000.j2c
> ```

The file name before the last underscore can change and include more underscores.
So I guess I need to find out how many numbers are to the right of the last underscore and add the correct number of zeros to get 6 numbers.
How do I do that?

Comment: `%1` constitutes the first argument of the batch file here, right? or is it meant literally??

Comment: it is meant literally :). the software that creates the sequences names them like this for some reason.

Comment: Okay... so what part of the file name could contain more underscores then (as you said in the last paragraph)?

Comment: this part: %1.j2c can look different. the software takes movie files or image sequences as input and converts them to .j2c image sequences. if one inputs a movie it always looks like this: %1.j2c_10.j2c. If you input an image sequence, the software will use the file name of the input sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, the pattern for the image files is `*_*.j2c`.

Since the leading file name part may contain multiple `_`, a trick can be used: `for` provides the possibility to split iterated items into pieces by giving `~` modifiers; supposing the variable is `%I`, a `%~nI` returns the file name, `%~xI` the extension, `%~nxI` file name plus extension (see `for /?`).
If no wildcards `*`, `?` are used, splitting is done without accessing the file system; so we can use this for string manipulation operations. In order to apply this to our task at hand, we need to replace every `_` by the path separator `\`.
There are two nested `for` loops; the outer one iterates through all the image files, and the inner one receives each file name plus ext. from the outer and iterates just once, where the path string splitting feature is (mis-)used for our needs.

The following code snippet uses the described trick  to extracted the part after the last `_` of the file name, which is the number to be padded with 6 leading zeros then. See also the explanatory `rem` comments:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "IMAGES=*_*.j2c"
set "DIGITS=6" & rem add more padding `0`s below if DIGITS > 12!
rem loop through all images that match the pattern given above;
rem since there is a wildcard `*`, the file system is accessed:
for %%I in ("%IMAGES%") do (
    rem now let us extract the portion between the last `_` and the ext.;
    rem for this we replace every `_` by `\`, so the item looks like a file path;
    rem then we split off the file name portion of the path-like string;
    rem since there are no more wildcards, the file system is NOT accessed:
    set "ARG=%%~nxI"
    set "FPTH=%%~fI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%F in ("!ARG:_=\!") do (
        rem extract and pad the numeric file name portion:
        set "VAL=000000000000%%~nF"
        set "VAL=!VAL:~-%DIGITS%!"
        rem rebuild file name; the `|` ensures that only the part
        rem after the last `_` is replaced by the padded number:
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        set "ARG=%%~F|"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "ARG=!ARG:%%~nxF|=!!VAL!%%~xF"
    )
    ren "!FPTH!" "!ARG:\=_!"
    endlocal
    endlocal
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The great advantage of this method is that we do not need to know the number of `_` characters (opposed to something like `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_"`, where the number of tokens is fixed).

Comment: Okay... so see my edit upon your [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938114/how-do-i-add-leading-zeros-to-an-image-sequence-in-windows-batch#comment55640327_33938114);

Comment: How do I use the script? I tried putting it in the same folder as the sequence and I tried to enter the full path into the IMAGES variable. But it only echos "ren path/to/sourcename_1.j2c path/to/000001.j2c", but does not actually rename the files. And as I understand it, the script will remove the file name and only keep the numbers, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry, there was an `ECHO` I used for testing, which I forgot to remove... the script extracts the numeric part of the file name, pads it with `6` leading zeros and reassembes the file name then; you can use the script as is in the directory where the images are, or you can provide the full path to your image files in the `IMAGES` variable, like `set "IMAGES=D:\full\path\to\image\dir\*_*.j2c";

Comment: I saw that and removed the ECHO, but then it says syntax error in the cmd window.

Comment: Yes, the problem was I provided a full path as the new file name for the `ren` command, but it should be a pure file name only -- I fixed that; I also fixed an issue that the original file name was lost, so now the new file names should be like the old one but with the numeric part padded...

Comment: I see, now it works great :)!! Just one more thing: the file %1.j2c_1.j2c will be renamed to %_000001.j2c. The rest of the files will be renamed correctly to %1.j2c_000....j2c. But I can just search replace for %1.j2c before using your script.

Answer (score 1):

this was a little bit challenging (but a little) :

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: path to the directory with the files
set "files_dir=."
pushd "%files_dir%"
for %%# in (*_*j2c) do (
    set "filename=%%~nx#"
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_." %%A in ("!filename!") do (
        set "num=%%C"
        call ::strlen0 num numlen
        if !numlen! LSS 6 (

            for /l %%] in (!numlen! ; 1 ; 6 ) do (
                set "num=0!num!"
            )

            ren %%A.%%B_%%C.%%D  %%A.%%B_!num!.%%D

        ) else (
           echo %%# will be not processed - more than or 6 numbers
        )
    )
)

endlocal & (
    popd
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)

:: taken from http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=424
:strlen0  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```

Comment: @schmiddl - if you have questions - go ahead.