# rename mutiple files in windows folder

Tags: cmd

If I try this command:

```
forfiles /M *.WAV /C "cmd /c rename @file temp.WAV"
```

I get this error :

> a duplicate file name exist, or the file cannot be found

I want that like windows i can add to all the rest files that exist a number like that:

```
temp.WAV
temp (2).WAV
temp (3).WAV
temp (4).WAV
temp (5).WAV
```

I tried several time and method and didn't success:

forfiles /M *.WAV /C "cmd /c rename @file temp.WAV

> a duplicate file name exist, or the file cannot be found

Comment: You can prefix your `cmd /C ...` with `echo ` to see how (and whether) the loop variable is being inserted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows bat file to rename multiple files with custom names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416981/windows-bat-file-to-rename-multiple-files-with-custom-names)